# "Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault."

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a program that calculates the product of two large, dense matrices. When I use dimensions 200 x 200 for the matrices the program works fine, but as soon as I go to 300 x 300 I get an popup window saying "Assignment2.exe has stopped working..." I ran the debugger and I get this error message: "Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault."

I know the obvious culprit is that the size of the matrices is too large, but I'm wondering if there is any way to optimize my program so it can handle larger matrices (without changing the function prototypes, as these are set in stone for the assignment). In MATLAB I am able to handle larger matrix sizes than this. I appreciate your help. Thanks!

### Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <random>

using namespace std;

int matrix_multiply(int n1, int n2, int n3, double *a, double *b, double *c);
int matrix_fill_random(int n1, int n2, double *a);
int matrix_print(int n1, int n2, double *a);


int matrix_multiply(int n1, int n2, int n3, double *a, double *b, double *c)
{
    int i;
    int j;
    int k;

    for (i=0;i<n1;i++) {
        for (j=0;j<n3;j++) {
            *(c+(i*n3)+j) = 0;
            for (k=0;k<n2;k++) {

                *(c+(i*n3)+j) += (*(a+(i*n2)+k) * (*(b+(k*n3)+j)));
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int matrix_fill_random(int n1, int n2, double *a)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<(n1*n2);i++) {
        *(a+i) = rand() % 20001 - 10000;
        *(a+i) /= 10000;
    }
    return 0;
}

int matrix_print(int n1, int n2, double *a)
{
    int i;
    int j;

    cout << "\n" << endl;

    for (i=0;i<n1;i++) {
        for (j=0;j<n2;j++) {
            if (*(a+(i*n2)+j) >= 0) {
                cout << " ";
            }
            cout << *(a+(i*n2)+j) << "\t";
        }
        cout << " " << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main() {

    int numRowsA;
    int numColsA;
    int numColsB;
    int numIterations;
    int i;
    srand((unsigned int)time(0));

    cout << "Please enter in the number of rows for Matrix A: ";
    cin >> numRowsA;
    cout << "Please enter in the number of columns for Matrix A: ";
    cin >> numColsA;
    cout << "Please enter in the number of columns for Matrix B: ";
    cin >> numColsB;
    cout << "Please enter in the number of iterations for repeating the multiplication: ";
    cin >> numIterations;

    double A[numRowsA][numColsA];
    double B[numColsA][numColsB];
    double C[numRowsA][numColsB];

    matrix_fill_random(numRowsA,numColsA,(&A[0][0]));
    matrix_fill_random(numColsA,numColsB,(&B[0][0]));

    clock_t beforeMult;
    clock_t afterMult;
    clock_t ticks;
    float seconds;
    float secondsPerIteration;

    beforeMult = clock();

    for (i=0;i<numIterations;i++){
        matrix_multiply(numRowsA,numColsA,numColsB,(&A[0][0]),(&B[0][0]),(&C[0][0]));
        delete C;
    }

    afterMult = clock();

    ticks = afterMult - beforeMult;
    seconds = (float(ticks))/numIterations;
    secondsPerIteration = seconds/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    cout << "The number of total clock ticks is: " << ticks << endl;
    cout << "The number of ticks per multiplication is: " << seconds << endl;
    cout << "The number of seconds per multiplication is: "  << secondsPerIteration << endl;

    delete A;
    delete B;
    delete C;
}
```

Comment: You don't seem to use `new` anywhere, but I see some `delete` statements!?! That makes no sense, drop the `delete` statements.

Comment: *Where* did the debugger give this message? More to the point, making arrays that big on the stack is a bad idea.

Comment: `C` is being deleted numerous times without ever being `new`ed, too.

Answer (score 2):

It is CLEARLY wrong to do :

```
delete A;
delete B;
delete C;
```

since `A`, `B` and `C` are created here:

```
double A[numRowsA][numColsA];
double B[numColsA][numColsB];
double C[numRowsA][numColsB];
```

and there is no `new` in those lines. If you didn't call `new` to create something, you shouldn't be using `delete`. And *IF* you use `new` to create two-dimensional arrays, you most likely need to use a loop to allocate the columns for each row, and then use the same in reverse to delete it - using `delete []`, as you are deleting an array.

The above code is also not C++ standards compliant, as the size of any array in standard C++ must be a compile-time constant. You are reading the size from the user, so the size is clearly NOT compile-time constants. And using large values of columns and rows is likely to cause problems with allocating space on the stack, even if the compiler allows it. Most systems have a default of around 1-4MB of stack-size (so a maximum of around 500k doubles at the very most). Once you have used that up, it's "game over", there is nothing you can do to recover at that point. So it's best to avoid running out of stack. Which brings back the idea of a loop to allocate the right amount of memory. However, I would suggest that you use `std::vector` rather than raw pointers or arrays, something like this:

```
std::vector<std::vector <double> > A;

A.resize(numrowsa);
for(int i = 0; i < numrowsa; i++)
{
    A[i].resize(numcolsa); 
}
```

And similarly for B and C.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment.  I set up the vectors as you suggested and re-ran the program, and I get the same error.  However, this time the debugger gives a specific line number (this is the line producing the error:         *(a+i) = rand() % 20001 - 10000;

Comment: I would suggest that you re-arrange your code to NOT pass pointers to your array elements - it won't work for vectors anyway, since the memory for the vector is not contiguous. Pass `vector<vector< double> >&` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `new` operator worked for me, as in the following code:

```
double *A = new double[numRowsA*numColsA];
double *B = new double[numColsA*numColsB];
double *C = new double[numRowsA*numColsB];
```